# Why is my clipboard-manipulating application behaving differently when run outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-4.5, clipboard

I have a console app with an "output type" of "Windows Application" (to achieve a headless behavior, i.e. no UI, no console window).  The purpose is to "clean" text in the Windows clipboard, i.e. trim all leading and trailing whitespace and remove formatting.

It works great when debugging, but when I run it from explorer, it just clears the clipboard contents.

Here's my code:

```
[STAThread]
internal static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var currentClipboardText = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText();

    // only if the clipboard has text; leave any other content intact.
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentClipboardText))
    {
        currentClipboardText = currentClipboardText.Trim();
        var pattern =  @"[\t\r\n\v\f\u2028\u2029]"; // match vert. whitesp & tabs
        currentClipboardText = Regex.Replace(currentClipboardText, pattern, " "); 
        System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(currentClipboardText);                
    }
}
```

Sample input with formatting in MS Word, copied to clipboard:

[image]

After I run the program in the dubugger (either in "debug" mode or "release" mode, makes no difference), here is the result pasted back into Word from the clipboard:

[image]

If I do the same excercise but run the program by double-clicking on it in Windows explorer (i.e. in the `\bin\Debug` directory), there is no text left on the clipboard to paste into Word:

[image]

What is the difference here?  Why isn't it working outside of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, data placed on the system Clipboard with SetDataObject is automatically cleared from the Clipboard when the application exits.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597039(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)

Use `System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(currentClipboardText, true);` instead to keep the data in the clipboard after the application exits.

Comment: Interesting.  Now I guess my question is: why *doesn't* it clear when debugging?

Comment: @adv12 -- but it gets it's on child process, right?

Comment: now with the change, the app is crashing when run from explorer.  Still works fine from VS debug.

Comment: @roryap Just to add some more confusion into the mix: My visual studio (2015) does not hold on to the clipboard data

Comment: @roryap clipboard operations can be blocked externally. You should probably print out the exception you are receiving and post it here

Comment: Here's the exception message: OpenClipboard Failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401D0 (CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN)).  Googling it produces results all over the map.  No help there so far.

Comment: @roryap I would guess that another application has got the clipboard open and is blocking you.

Comment: I guess so.  Hard to tell.  Either way, you solved my issue in the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code, and it does not work when debugging. I changed the line:

System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(currentClipboardText);

With:

System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(currentClipboardText);

And it worked when debugging, and when not debugging. I think what is happening is that Word is no longer recognizing the DataObject as being paste-able text.

I hope this solves your problem.